# Cakephp 3.0 ConnectionManager, getDataSource in Controller

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3.0, what's the equivalent of calling `getDataSource()` from inside a controller (like `$this->ModelName->getDataSource()`in cakephp 2.x)?

I have tried this:

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('my_connection');
```

Since this connection is connected already, why do I need to provide 'my_connection'?

How can I can get the DataSource from inside a Controller in CakePHP 3.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Database\ConnectionManager::get() has been added. It replaces getDataSource()

CakePHP Cookbook 3

Comment: It's not especially clear what you expect the asker to do with this information. Can you [edit] to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Begin, commit and rollback are now functions on the connection, not the data source. Use `$conn = ConnectionManager::get($connectionName)` and then use `$conn->begin()`, `$conn->commit()` and `$conn->rollback()`.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions

And use `$this->Table->defaultConnectionName()` to get the connection name to pass to get.

Answer (score 0):

"my_connection" should be defined in cakephp 3 config
.go to cakephp/config/app.php

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cake',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
```

connection name is "default" for this case.

Each Model that used in controller have one Connection.
You can get connection in controller from model by this method.

```
$model=TableRegistry::get('table_name');
$connection = $model->connection();
```